# Determine different cells for iPhone and iPad in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: With 3 sections each consist different cells?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have used the below answer which works great for `tableviewCell` which consist only 1 section. but I am not able to achieve that while `tableview` have more than 1 section

```
if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib;
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
            nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"exampleCell" owner:self options:nil];
        } else {
            nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iPadexampleCell" owner:self options:nil];
        }

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    switch (indexPath.section) {

        case 0:
        {
            if (deviceSize.height > 737 ) {
                cell = iPadexampleCell1;
            }
            else {
                cell = exampleCell1;
            }
        }
            break;

        case 1:
        {
            if (deviceSize.height > 737 ) {
                cell = iPadexampleCell2;
            }
            else {
                cell = exampleCell2;
            }
        }
            break;


        case 2:
        {
            if (deviceSize.height > 737 ) {
                cell = iPadexampleCell3;
            }
            else {
                cell = exampleCell3;
            }
        }
            break;

        default:
        {
            cell = exampleCell1;
        }
            break;
    }
```

By this code I tried to bring the cells to display but am not able to present the received text in label present in exampleCell1 and ipadexampleCell1(e.g. both cell have *UserNameLabel*).

I check the response and received data.

Kindly help in this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes all are static cells

Comment: As per this code, the cells iPadexampleCell1, exampleCell1, iPadexampleCell2, exampleCell2, iPadexampleCell3, exampleCell3 are not initialized. Are you initializing them somewhere else?

Comment: yes i have initialized that too

Comment: So what happens when you set the label? I assume you would be setting the label something like `iPadexampleCell1.UserNameLabel.text = @"some text";`